# Can we calculate how many records can a user can save in EE.

Tags: data-storage

I want to have a approximate calculation of how many records per user can store if they are using EE. As we know that per record is 2 KB and storage limit for per user is 20 MB. Then it will be around 10,000 records right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just "Data Storage Allocation Per User License". Actually one user can store more than 10000 records too. Its just that the total storage is the limit.

Ex - A Professional Edition organization with 100 users receives 2000MB Data Storage because 100 users multiplied by 20 MB per user is 2,000 MB. So this 2000MB is shared across user. there is no **individual** limit